# How could we allow non-root users to control a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, sudo, services, non-root-user

With `sysvinit`, a `sudoers` entry like this would suffice:

```
%webteam cms051=/sbin/service httpd *
```

This would allow for commands such as:

- `sudo service httpd status`
- `sudo service httpd restart`

Now, with `systemd`, the service name is the final argument. I.e., the service restart would be done with:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Naturally, I thought defining the command as `systemctl * httpd.service` would work but that would allow something like `systemctl restart puppet.service httpd.service` which is not the desired effect.

With that being considered, what would be the best way allow non-root users to control a `systemd` service then? This doesn't need to be `sudoers`; perhaps a file permission change may be sufficient?

Comment: I haven't touched a `sudo` configuration in a while, but couldn't you just do something like `cms051=systemctl * httpd.service` ?

Comment: This would allow you to restart any service then. I should have included that tidbit in the question. Sorry.

Comment: None of the answers here even touches upon PolicyKit, as described in answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496982/5132 , even though the question states that the mechanism does not have to be `sudo`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just add all needed commands to `sudoers` separately:

```
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl stop httpd.service
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl start httpd.service
```

Comment: I was hoping to capture all unit commands but if I have to itemize them, then I guess that's what I will have to do.

Comment: status isn't useful, as any user can do that

Comment: What is `cms051`?

Comment: @kevin cms501 is a host name or an host name list alias. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

Comment: So what will happen if I invoke systemctl restart http.service mariadb.service ;-) ?

Probably mariadb will be restarted also

Comment: @MarekWajdzik sudo does not allow extra arguments if one does not explicitly allowed with `*` or similar patterns.

Comment: Does this still work on a recent Linux system (e.g. Ubuntu)? Because if I do so I am getting an authentication request: `Authentication is required to start...`.

Comment: @Robert are you using the `sudo` command, even after setting these commands to run passwordless.

Answer (score 75):

@jofel's answer was exactly what I needed to get a working setup. POsting this for anyone else stumbling on this question. I needed a way to have `capistrano` restart my Ruby application after deploying from my local machine. That means I needed passwordless access to restarting `systemd` services. THIS is what I have and it works wonderfully!

*Note*: my user and group is called `deployer`
Put code in a custom file here: `/etc/sudoers.d/deployer`
Code:

```
%deployer ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start my_app
%deployer ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop my_app
%deployer ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart my_app
```

Comment: I need to add that after logging in as the user `deployer` in the case, you should run the `systemctl` command with sudo.

Comment: This worked well for me, awesome!

Comment: If on CentOS:

```deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl reload httpd,/bin/systemctl status httpd```

Comment: hmhm, somehow it still doesn't work for me on CentOS 7.9...

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @goldfishalpha It worked on Ubuntu 20.04.5 for me. Make sure if you are using the beginning % you are naming a group. You must omit that if you are directly naming a user.

Answer (score 16):

Create a command alias with the commands you want them to have access to.  Then assign the group to that command alias:

```
Cmnd_Alias APACHE-SVC = /usr/bin/systemctl stop httpd, /usr/bin/systemctl start httpd, /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd

%webteam ALL=APACHE-SVC
```

It is also good practice to place any edits in your /etc/sudoers.d/filename rather than directly editing the sudoers file.  Make sure to point to your .d/filename in the sudoers, which most new distros do anyway.  Placing these 2 lines in your sudoers should do the trick:

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Note: That # in front of the includedir is not a comment.  It must remain.

Comment: How add chance to execute stop/start/restart whithout enter password?

Comment: Best answer IMO. Everyone should add a command alias and work with this.

Comment: Managed to lock myself out of my system by doing this, since one doesn't have the automatic safety check of visudo and sudo does not aut roll back to a working version.
Calling this "good practice" seems questionable to me.

Answer (score 8):

**It's safest to itemize them as [jofel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192714/3629) suggests.**

If I wanted to allow someone to use a limited subset of a command's abilities, I would not trust wildcards in a sudoers line to do it.  Even if the language was more expressive than shell globs, there are just too many corner cases to keep track of.

The "`service httpd *`" line is *relatively* safe because (verify this:) `service` only has one useful flag (`--status-all`) which doesn't do anything particularly sensitive, and (verify this too:) `/etc/init.d/httpd` will only accept the command lines you want to allow.

If there are so many combinations that listing them out becomes awkward, you should probably question what you are doing.  But you could give them access to a carefully written helper script that runs the command for them (much like `/etc/init.d/http`).  Even in this case you should be as precise and explicit as possible to list out exactly what commands and options are allowed, and don't pass any user input directly to the target command.

Answer (score 8):

In RHEL8:

An alternate option is to have an `httpd.service` file under webteam home directory  `~/.config/systemd/user` and they can start/stop/enable etc themselves:

```
systemctl --user enable httpd.service
systemctl --user start httpd.service
```

Validated that the above works as long as the user has permission to start the service.  This seems useful on dev systems allowing the developers to also do timers and pipelines effectively with all the configs available to them as supposed to in devops/ops hands.

Also seems like it would be beneficial for moving it to prod with the whole startup sequence tested in an actual server environment using the operations built httpd, and not have the devs say "but it worked on my laptop and broke when I pushed to dev".  But I am just thinking and writing here.

Best online ref, as the systemd user documentation is not copious:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. - Here's another in depth look at the approach: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-systemd-service-without-root-sudo/

Comment: This answer describes how to run a service as a non root user. What this question is about is a non root user controlling a standard systemd service, the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Since many (most?) Unixes and Linuxes that use the `systemd` init system also provide the `service` command as a high-level interface to it ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/867334)), often could simply **keep the same configuration** you're used to from the `sysvinit` init system.

So, in a a file `/etc/sudoers.d/webteam` you would write:

```
%webteam cms051=/sbin/service httpd *
```

which then enables users in group `webteam` to use all actions on service `httpd` when calling with `sudo`, such as `sudo service httpd restart`.