# Service functions without sudo

Tags: sudo, services

My service on CentOS is configured to run under a certain user in its
config file under `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Service]
User=buildman
```

When I am `su`ed as buildman, I can run:

```
systemctl status myservice.service
```

but if I try to do `start` or `stop`, it prompts me for password.

If I do:

```
sudo systemctl status myservice.service
```

it does not prompt me because I have configured `visudo`:

```
%buildman ALL= NOPASSWD:  /bin/systemctl * myservice.service
```

But why doesn't service stop and start work like status? I would like
to enable buildman to execute these service commands without sudo or
password.

The primary reason for this is that I need to enable service restart
from Jenkins and I ran into problems running sudo from its
container, which complained that I needed a "TTY" to run it.

Comment: tried sudo /bin/systemctl start myservice  (giving full path, like configured in visudo) ?

Comment: your suggestion still requires `sudo`

Comment: that's not a suggestion yet :), just a question to figure out some details.
Did it work with start / stop too if specifyin full path ?

Comment: Just in case one more check: %buildman denotes a group, not user.  Does that group exist?Does  user buildman belongs to it?

Comment: yes, that group does exist

Comment: Related: [How could we allow non-root users to control a systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service)

Comment: Another related question, currently with better more general answers, is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496982/5132 .

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `start/stop` and `status` is that `status` does not alter system state.

Any modification of system-wide state or configuration requires system-wide administration privileges -- hence sudo. Reading the 'status' of a service is a read-only operation and so is not normally protected.

It's worth noting that user services do not require sudo. For example

```
systemctl --user start bobsburgers
```

will succeed when issued by bob, but only by bob. (Root will not be able to start this service because it is not a root user service.)

So if the service you're interested in here does not alter system-wide state, you could install it as a user service

```
systemctl --user enable bobsburgers
```

The standard configuration is to place your service file in `~/.config/systemd/user`. As long as the service itself does not require global rights, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`status` command does not require superuser rights, it works w/o `sudo` too.
`start` and `stop` do require `sudo`. You can avoid entering password but not specifying sudo.

Comment: I tried 1 and it didn't work. How do I do your #2 suggestion?

Comment: You still need sudo in front of the command for other than status.
Assuming sudo config is correct it won't requre password

Comment: this OP asks for a way to do away with sudo

Comment: I was wrong about full path guess, sudo config do require full path indeed. sorry, will correct my answer. But I don't think  you can avoid sudo for a non-root user. I
OP asked 'without sudo OR password' - I suggesed w/o password option