# Capabilities to start a systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, capabilities

I'm starting a process with the `cap_kill` capability and use this process to kill other services. However I'd like to be able to restart these service with a `systemctl restart xxx`

Is there a capability to allow this without having to run it with sudo?

Answer (score 1):

To allow a non-root user to restart a system service, you can either use `sudo` (which you say you want to avoid), or PolKit.

Please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497011) for instructions on how to configure PolKit rules.