# Controlling systemd system service as user

Tags: systemd, sudo, polkit

I have several services that need to be user-controlled and I can't use them as user services (their requirement is system service with root access), plus there is weird GROUP/216 bug that I haven't been able to fix no matter what I try.

I have created template service with name my-daemon@.service, so it has to be launched as `systemctl start my-daemon@<parameter>.service`.
The parameter is alphanumeric string, no spaces, tabs, special characters, etc.

I have read [Restarting systemd service only as a specific user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496982/restarting-systemd-service-only-as-a-specific-user/497011) and tried the "sudo approach", but as I am using template service, it creates conciderable security problems.

Example sudo line that allows user username to stop one service:

`username ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop my-daemon@*.service`

However, I am perfectly aware that this line is security nightmare, as it lets me do this command too:

`sudo systemctl stop my-daemon@xyz firewalld.service`

And here are two example polkit files, one with static service name and second is template. Both are in /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/ :

`polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon2.service" &&
        subject.user == "username") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});`

`polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon@.service" &&
        subject.user == "username") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});`

Questions:

1. How can I fix the sudo statement so it will only allow me to run selected services as user username? I read the man, tried and failed to fix it myself.
2. I would much prefer to use polkit, I have polkit version 0.112, through journalctl I can see polkit added new rules but I can't get the rules right, even when I try static service name it doesn't allow me to control it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Partial answer based on https://superuser.com/questions/1064616/polkit-systemd-interaction : While polkit version is OK, systemd is not, only v210. Therefore, it seems I won't be able to do it through polkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tests and research, I can finally answer myself.

1) Not possible in itself. No way to write something that resembles [a-zA-Z0-9_-]* regexp. It would be possible if I knew precisely how many characters the string should have, but it varies.

2) As said in my comment, option 2 is out too, there isn't required systemd support in my version of systemd. Upgrading required system packages would be possible, but not in the time I have.

So I went with the option one with a twist. I don't allow user to control service directly, I allow to start script that does all the checking I can't do in sudo. If everything is OK, *then* the service is called.

Comment: Writing a script in this case seems to be the most sensible option anyway, since this is the level at which `Cmnd_Alias` in `sudoers` works ... i.e. instead of whitelisting `systemctl` carefully craft a script which can be used in a `Cmnd_Alias`. If you wanted to make it seamless, you could place the script in the user's `PATH` and call it `systemctl` but limit the scope of commands/services this script enables the user to act upon.