# Restart a systemd daemon, for continuous integration, without root?

Tags: systemd

We have a nodejs based server that is configured to be launched by systemd and on our dev server new versions are deployed via continuous integration. The issue we have is that a non-root user can not restart the application using the systemctl command, so we are curious how we should approach the problem?

The command we tried:

```
sudo systemctl start my-nodejs-server
```

And the contents of the systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=NodeJS Based Server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=myserver-user
Group=myserver-userh
Environment=ENV=production NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/myserver-user/my-nodejs-server/
#ExecStart=/home/myserver-user/my-nodejs-server/scripts/appctl.sh restart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node lib
Restart=on-failure
```

I have also tried the following command, as suggested:

```
systemctl --user start my-nodejs-server
```

but I get the following:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

We are running on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: `systemctl status...` is not going to start anything.

Comment: Copy/pasted the wrong line for example. Updated.

Comment: And what does status report after starting the service? Also note, if you are running it from home, you want `systemctl --user start myservice`...

Comment: Tried, but running into an issue.

Comment: Your session is broken. Fix that first.

Comment: Fixed with `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"` if doing `sudo su - myuser` or a proper login (`ssh myuser@localhost`) to the given account resolved that. Do you want to put all this as an answer, so you get credit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72903/discussion-between-andre-m-and-jasonwryan).

Answer (score 2):

For my needs a 'system unit file' is needed, rather than a 'user unit file' (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances)), since the latter lives in the user's home directory and is only for programs that are meant to run for the duration of a login session.

The solution I ultimately went with is described in the following answer:

> [How could we allow non-root users to control a system.d service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service)

Essentially you give the user sudo privileges for running specific commands. Here it is:

```
myserver-user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start my-nodejs-server
myserver-user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop my-nodejs-server
myserver-user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart my-nodejs-server
```

Note that if you want to apply this privilege to a group, then use a percentage symbol in front of the identifier so:

```
%myserver-group ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start my-nodejs-server
%myserver-group ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop my-nodejs-server
%myserver-group ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart my-nodejs-server
```

Also, based on the referenced answer, I'll probably change the deployment user to be `deployment`, or something similar, to avoid the deployment user being the same one that is running the application.

Comment: You could also compact those into a single line, each command delimited with a comma.