# how to restart a buggy HTTP service - for continuous testing and integration

Tags: debian, systemd, http

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422926/50557) is perhaps related to the one I am asking here.

This is in the context of https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/ (a GPLv3+ software for Linux, currently -april 2020- in *active* development, which is a specialized C++ multithreaded web application for Linux, so **work in progress** on April 8, 2020)

I am renting a VPS on host `b-star-y.tech` running Linux/Debian/Buster.

I am developing with others [helpcovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/), a multi-threaded GPLv3+ web application software coded for Linux in C++17.

I am not familiar with [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), which is used by Debian/Buster on that host, or with [`docker`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))

I would like to implement **the following infinite loop** in a `git clone`d file tree.

- `git pull`
- `make`
- run `./helpcovid -D -T2` with both stderr and stdout redirected to some file.
- `sleep 5`

and **repeat indefinitely**.

I am tempted to use a [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job, or perhaps `atd` with `batch`

Is there a better way with `systemd` ?

You may email me to `basile@starynkevitch.net`

Comment: Yes, there is, and it isn't even systemd-specific.  But it involves code changes to the program, which currently does things in the wrong ways, and improvements to your cpp-httplib library, which does not actually have the requisite functionality as it stands.  It's probably too long for a detailed StackExchange answer.

Comment: That [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) library is not mine. Do you recommend switching to [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion)?

Comment: @JdeBP  please add your answer, including criticisms, but in constructive ways. Thanks. What exactly is designed wrong? Of course we do have bugs! Feel free to add [issues](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues)

Comment: @JdeBP or send me an email

Comment: I was actually thinking about an issue (and whether I have the time for that).  But I'll do you a broad overview here.

Comment: Waiting impatiently for your feedback, either here or by email

Answer (score 3):

For about a quarter of a century, now, we've had toolsets that allow unprivileged users to run nonce services ad hoc.  [Daniel J. Bernstein's daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) is one of the earliest.  One doesn't *have* to set up scan directories and other infrastructure.  One can just run a program under [`supervise`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/spuervise.html) directly.  [M. Bernstein's UCSPI-TCP toolset](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html), furthermore, is an example of the several toolsets that we've had for a similar length of time that handle services that need to accept TCP connections and do stuff.

There are other toolsets that do the same, without need for systemd, and of course with systemd one can *also* set up ad hoc per-user services.

It is 2020.  There is no good reason to write new programs that use the rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism.  There's no need for any of that PID file code that you've written.

Similarly, it's a good idea to write a TCP server so that it can *inherit* its listening socket, as an already open file descriptor.  This is in fact the way that *system-wide* services, run from inted, conventionally have operated since the 1980s.  It can be done with per-user services, too.  The s6 and nosh toolsets, and indeed systemd, all provide ways in which a service can be given its listening socket.  There's no need for *any* of that  nonce URL parsing code that you have written, which like many off-the-cuff parsers doesn't handle all of the forms that a URL can take.

Unfortunately, as I said, your `cpp-httplib` library does not have a constructor or function member where it can be *given* the file descriptor for the listening socket.  This is a major oversight in the design of that library, given that inheriting socket file descriptors has been a normal practice for three and a bit decades.

## something *other than* systemd

Both [my nosh toolset](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/) and [Laurent Bercot's s6 toolset](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/) provide ways to run nonce programs as ad hoc per-user services.

Under the nosh toolset, one would have a `helpcovid` subdirectory, with a `service` subdirectory beneath that containing the various programs for handling the service.

`helpcovid/service/start` and `helpcovid/service/stop` are fairly minimal:

```
#!/bin/nosh                                                         
#Start file generated from ./helpcovid.socketand ./helpcovid.service
true
```

```
#!/bin/nosh
#Stop file generated from ./helpcovid.socketand ./helpcovid.service
true
```

The meat is in `helpcovid/service/run` and `helpcovid/service/service`:

```
#!/bin/nosh
#Run file generated from ./helpcovid.socketand ./helpcovid.service
#Starynkevitch helpcovid listening socket
tcp-socket-listen --systemd-compatibility ::0 50002
envdir env
setenv LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8
chdir /home/basile/dev/helpcovid/test
./service
```

```
#!/bin/nosh
#Service file generated from ./helpcovid.service
#Starynkevitch helpcovid service
sh -c 'exec /home/basile/dev/helpcovid/work/helpcovid ${flags}'
```

And `helpcovid/service/restart` controls the restart logic:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Restart file generated from ./helpcovid.service
sleep 5
exec true   # ignore script arguments
```

This one would run by giving it to a per-user instance of `service-manager`.  The toolset does the binding and listening on the socket, reads environment variable configuration from an envdir, and passes the open file descriptor to the eventual program using the `LISTEN_FDS` protocol, having changed working directory to the place where your test `webroot/` directory lives.

A similar structure is employed by s6, although the tool names are different (e.g. [`s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder.html) rather than [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-listen.xml)) and the restart logic is differently handled.  s6 does not require a service manager.  Like the original daemontools, one can just run [`s6-supervise`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-supervise.html) by hand to invoke a service:

```
s6-supervise ./helpcovid/service/
```

I'm not going to go into a lot of detail, as the main point is that not having systemd is no excuse for bad dæmon design (indeed good dæmon design principles *originated with* much older non-systemd mechanisms) and that the mechanisms for passing open file descriptors for listening sockets apply to and can be used with more than just systemd.

## systemd

The aforegiven programs were actually converted from a systemd *socket unit* and *service unit* that I quickly threw together.  They show how one would set up a per-user service on systemd, with files in `~/.config/systemd/user/`:

```
# helpcovid.socket
[Unit]
Description=Starynkevitch helpcovid listening socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=50002
Accept=No
[Install]
Wanted-By=default.target
```

```
# helpcovid.service
[Unit]
Description=Starynkevitch helpcovid service
[Service]
Environment=LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
ExecStart=/home/basile/dev/helpcovid/work/helpcovid ${flags}
WorkingDirectory=/home/basile/dev/helpcovid/test
#This has no meaning for systemd.
EnvironmentDirectory=env
```

This is controlled with the likes of `systemctl --user start helpcovid.socket`.

In the world of systemd, these *are* the configuration files.  The user wants to change the TCP port number?  The user changes the `ListenStream=` setting.  No need for redundant extra environment variables for setting the locale.  The user just sets the actual `LC_ALL` (or whatever) variable in the manner shown.

## logging

Logging is also handled by service management.  The nosh toolset and s6 way is to feed the standard output and standard error through a pipe to a secondary service running `cyclog`, `s6-log`, or something.  systemd stuffs log output into the user part of the centralized systemd journal, which you use `journalctl --user` to read.

## your program

Your program needs to log to `std::clog` (i.e. standard error), call `setlocale()` with `NULL` to read the standard environment variables, and have code that handles the `LISTEN_FDS` mechanism.  There are plenty of choices for that last, from a non-portable helper function library that comes with systemd to other people's more portable workalikes.

It's definitely far less code to put in than all of that TCP port number parsing code, rickety and dangerous PID file code, and `HELPCOVID_LOCALE` and `--locale` code that can be taken out this way.  ☺

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  [*Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).   Frequently Given Answers.
- https://github.com/jdebp/nosh/blob/ddb422c9e6db11aee1c22a171bcc729edc7fe1c3/source/listen.cpp#L1
- Issues:

  - https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/30
  - https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/31
  - https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/32
  - https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/33
  - https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/34

Comment: Thanks a big lot for your feedback