# How to use service to start/stop app with non-root access?

Tags: linux, users, root, services, non-root-user

RHEL 7.5

Currently installed an application as root in `/app`. As part of administration, application will start/stop using `/sbin/chkconfig` & `/sbin/service` utilities

All the application binaries and their dependents are currently owned by root(uid/gid).

In our environment, root access(sudo) is provided for fours weeks only, on fresh production machine. We need to avoid relying on root access.

So, for future access to this application, we would like create `appuser` a non-root user

```
appuser:x:1983:1983:appuser:/home/appuser:/bin/bash
```

and `chown`/`chgrp`  application directory structure to `appuser`

---

As `appuser`, Does it require root access to start/stop app using `service` & `chkconfig`?

Comment: you cant use those commands without root per se. You define limited commands in sudo

Comment: Related: [How could we allow non-root users to control a systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service)

Comment: create a script maintained by root that starts / kills the service and give the user sudo access to precisely these files? then again, is it not normally part of a sysadmins job to maintain services?