# CentOS user can use sudo but cannot start/stop services

Tags: centos, permissions, acl

I want to know if it's possible to control user commands in linux. We have a group called **operators**, they are normal users but can view logs and such but cannot start/stop services. Is there any way to control ACL for each group? Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-systemd-service or https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service

Comment: This is applicable to another of our groups, but for now I'm looking for the opposite of this one. But I think I can just reverse this one for the operator group.